# Shell - renaming logfiles according to their timestamps

Tags: shell

I'm trying to rename logfiles with this format: logfile_access_server1.log according to their date of creation so that they have the following format: 20121128.log 20121127.log etc... and gzip them into another folder, using a shell script.

I've tried this:

```
    #! /bin/sh

for i in `ls *access*.log`
do
mv $i /home/log/$i$(date +%F-%T).gz
done
```

(I'm a noob in shell scripting and obviously it doesn't work)

Thanks in advance for your help

J.

Comment: Where do you get the date of file creation from?

Comment: from the logfile timestamp, is it possible?

Comment: that gives you the file modification time, not file creation time...

Comment: You're right, fair enough, I only need the date

Comment: You mean you want the timestamp of the file modified date in the filename. It is little confusing since you have used the current timestamp for renaming.

Comment: Yes you got it right, I want the timestamp of the file modified date in the filename

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
for filename in *access*.log; do
    basename=$(basename "$filename" .log)
    timestamp=$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$filename")" +%F-%T)
    mv "$filename" "/home/log/$basename.$timestamp.log"
done
```

Have you investigated [logrotate](http://man.cx/logrotate)?